# how to open new IE window on click of hyperlink

Tags: asp.net

"
      Text="<%#Eval('name')%>"
      Target="_blank"
      runat="server" />

here the text that i have binded to navigate url can be any url (eg:asp.net,google.com)

this is my code when i try to open a  new iE window

**as  my file is under an directory admin/abc.aspx**

now in the url it opens like this: http://localhost:5655/admin/www.asp.net

**but in the url  should be  like this www.asp.net so that this website opens**

any help would be great

thank you

Comment: BTW - you seriously don't need a server control for this scenario. What's wrong with `<a target="_blank" href="<%#Eval('name')%>"><%#Eval("name")%></a>`?

Answer (score 4):

remember to begin your urls with `http://` otherwise it will think it's a relative url.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple. Set the "Target" attribute of your asp:HyperLink to "_blank". Fill the url into NavigateUrl. It's going to open the link in a new Browser.

```
 <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkUrlValue" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Url")%>'  
  Text='<%#Eval("Url")%>' ForeColor="#8D34FF" Font-Underline="true")                                                                                                                   
  Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: please edit your answer and format the code to make it readable

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the URL starts with a protocol like `http://`

Comment: so where  should i add this line  of code. can u me give the entire syntax
Target="_blank"

Comment: here it does not  open a  new IE  window instaed of that it  takes the  exiting application window and then loads that website url in my application which should not  happen

 instead o fthet it  should open a  new ie  window and  load the  url

Comment: Your target is correct.  However your NavigateUrl is not, it needs to be:  NavigateUrl"http://<% #Eval('name')%>"

The problem there is that it assumes "http://" ideally you would have that in your data store or some code behind to append it.

Comment: Oops, type in the string where I was missing the equals.  NavigateUrl="

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<asp:HyperLink
  id="hyperlink1"
  NavigateUrl="<%# (Eval("URL").ToString().IndexOf("http://")!=-1 ? "http://":"")+Eval("name").ToString()%>"
  Text="<%#Eval('name')%>"
  Target="_blank"
  runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**final answer**

" Text="<%#Eval('name')%>" Target="_blank" runat="server"/>

NavigateUrl='<%# "http://" + Eval('name')%>'

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "http://" + Eval('name')%>'
```